# Why is iterative k-way merge O(nk^2)?

Tags: algorithm

k-way merge is the algorithm that takes as input k sorted arrays, each of size n. It outputs a single sorted array of all the elements.

It does so by using the "merge" routine central to the merge sort algorithm to merge array 1 to array 2, and then array 3 to this merged array, and so on until all k arrays have merged.

I had thought that this algorithm is O(kn) because the algorithm traverses each of the k arrays (each of length n) once. Why is it O(nk^2)?

Comment: You can get O(n k log k) by using a heap or a selection tree to select the next element from the k possible choices at each stage. E.g. Knuth Volume II Sorting and Searching section 5.4.1

Comment: algorithm selects pair's of array so you have comb(k 2) = k * (k-1) /2. Since each array has a size of n and merge take O(n) you get O(nk^2)

Comment: You can use a Queue and the time will be O(n log k) where n is the number of integers and k is the number of sorted arrays

Comment: @Dejel traversal through all elements will take O(nk). Using a heap, we can get O(nklogk). Can you elaborate on how to achieve O(nlogk)?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Because it doesn't traverse each of the k arrays once. The first array is traversed k-1 times, the first as merge(array-1,array-2), the second as merge(merge(array-1, array-2), array-3) ... and so on.

The result is k-1 merges with an average size of n*(k+1)/2 giving a complexity of O(n*(k^2-1)/2) which is O(nk^2).

The mistake you made was forgetting that the merges are done serially rather than in parallel, so the arrays are not all size n.

Comment: How'd you get the average size?

Comment: The first merge is of size 2n (two arrays of size n). The second is of size 3n (the accumulated array of 2n, and one of size n). You should be able to see that the kth pass is (k+1)n. The average size is approximately equal to half that or n(k+1)/2, any residual term won't affect O() analysis.

Answer (score 48):

Actually in the worst case scenario,there will be *n* comparisons for the first array, *2n* for the second, *3n* for the third and soon till *(k - 1)n*.
So now the complexity becomes simply

```
n + 2n + 3n + 4n + ... + (k - 1)n
= n(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + (k - 1))
= n((k - 1)*k) / 2
= n(k^2 - k) / 2
= O(nk ^ 2)
```

:-)

Comment: I know this is an ignorant question, but can you tell me how you know to get from step 2 to 3? In other words, why is the sum over (1...k-1) equal to ((k-1)*k)/2? Is this a formalization of what people refer to as Gauss's trick for adding a long series of numbers?

Comment: @user3208862 : this is because of Summation rule
when you calculate (1+2+3+...k) 
it equals k(k+1)/2
check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation for reference

Answer (score 16):

How about this:

Step 1:
Merge arrays (1 and 2), arrays (3 and 4), and so on. (k/2 array merges of 2n, total work kn).

Step 2:
Merge array (1,2 and 3,4), arrays (5,6 and 7,8), and so on (k/4 merges of 4n, total work kn).

Step 3:
Repeat...

There will be log(k) such "Steps", each with kn work. Hence total work done = O(k.n.log(k)).

Even otherwise, if we were to just sort all the elements of the array we could still merge everything in O(k.n.log(k.n)) time.

Comment: to be honest, i think this bottom up merge is much better than the one in OP's question

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to compare items 1 by 1 each time. 
You should simply maintain the most recent K items in a sorted set.
 You remove the smallest and relace it by its next element. This should be n.log(k)

Relevant [article](http://www.sinbadsoft.com/blog/sorting-big-files-using-k-way-merge-sort/). Disclaimer: I participated in writing it

Comment: Correct. But you need to mention that you are using there a heap (e.g . queue)

Comment: this what I meant by a "sorted set" in my answer. actually you need a sorted multiset. a heap is one possible implementation.

Comment: for your heap, you will eventually insert nk-1 elements into your structure. Since an insert costs O(log(k)), the complexity for the entire merge should be O(nklog(k)), not nlog(k) as you said. As stated in the question, n is the size of chunk. If we consider N to be the total size, we have N=nk therefore the complexity in regard to N is O(Nlog(k))

Answer (score 6):

> k-way merge is the algorithm that takes as input k sorted arrays, each of size n. It outputs a single sorted array of all the elements.
>
> I had thought that this algorithm is O(kn)

We can disprove that by contradiction. Define a sorting algorithm for m items that uses your algorithm with k=m and n=1. By the hypothesis, the sorting algorithm succeeds in O(m) time. Contradiction, it's known that any sorting algorithm has worst case at least O(m log m).

Comment: Just in case some one stumbles here, the worst case sorting time of nlogn is only for COMPARISON based sorting algorithms. Algos such as counting or bucket sort et al, are not comparison sorts and are only applicable when some restrictions about input are met. E.g. a quick look at counting sort tells you that if any element's value (say 100) is bigger than the array size, it would go out of bounds.

Answer (score 4):

1) You have k sorted arrays, each of size n. Therefore total number of elements = k * n

2) Take the first element of all k arrays and create a sequence. Then find the minimum of this sequence. This min value is stored in the output array. Number of comparisons to find the minimum of k elements is k - 1.

3) Therefore the   total number of comparisons 
   = (comparisons/element) * number of elements
   = (k - 1) * k * n 
   = k^2 * n   // approximately

Answer (score 3):

A common implementation keeps an array of indexes for each one of the k sorted arrays {i_1, i_2, i__k}. On each iteration the algorithm finds the minimum next element from all k arrays and store it in the output array. Since you are doing kn iterations and scanning k arrays per iteration the total complexity is O(k^2 * n).

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
Input: A[j] j = 1..k : k sorted arrays each of length n
Output: B : Sorted array of length kn

// Initialize array of indexes
I[j] = 0 for j = 1..k

q = 0

while (q < kn):
    p = argmin({A[j][I[j]]}) j = 1..k           // Get the array for which the next unprocessed element is minimal (ignores arrays for which I[j] > n)
    B[q] = A[p][I[p]]
    I[p] = I[p] + 1
    q = q + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have k arrays each with n elements. This means total k*n elements.
2. Consider it a matrix of k*n. To add first element to the merged/ final array, you need to compare heads of k arrays. This means for one element in final array you need to do k comparisons.

So from 1 and 2, for K*n elements, total time taken is O(k*k*n).

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to know the details or need some help with this, I'm going expand on Recurse's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11026293/828547) and follow-up comment

- We only need `k-1` merges because the last array is not merged with anything
- The formula for summing the terms of an arithmetic sequence is helpful; `Sn=n(a1 + an)2`

Stepping through the first 4 merges of `k` arrays with `n` elements

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------+
| Merge | Size of new array |    Note     |
+-------+-------------------+-------------+
| 1     | n+n  = 2n         | first merge  |
| 2     | 2n+n = 3n         |             |
| 3     | 3n+n = 4n         |             |
| 4     | 4n+n = 5n         |             |
| k-1   | (k-1)n+n = kn     | last merge  |
+-------+-------------------+-------------+
```

To find the average size, we need to sum all the sizes and divide by the number of merges (`k-1`). Using the formula for summing the first `n` terms, `Sn=n(a1 + an)2`, we only need the **first** and **last** terms:

- ***a1***=`2n` (first term)
- ***an***=`kn` (last term)

We want to sum all the terms so `n=k-1` (the number of terms we have). Plugging in the numbers we get a formula for the sum of all terms

`Sn = ( (k-1)(2n+kn) )/2`

However, to find the *average* size we must divide by the number of terms (`k-1`). This cancels out the `k-1` in the numerator and we're left with an average of size of

`(2n + kn)/2`

Now we have the average size, we can multiply it by the number of merges, which is `k-1`. To make the multiplication easier, ignore the `/2`, and just multiply the numerators:

```
  (k-1)(2n+kn)
= (k^2)n + kn - 2n
```

At this point you could reintroduce the `/2`, but there shouldn't be any need since it's clear the dominant term is `(k^2)*n`