# Modification to merge sort to implement merge sort with insertion sort Java

Tags: java, complexity-theory, mergesort

I want to implement a  modification to merge 
sort, where n/k sublists of length k are sorted using insertion sort and then merged using 
the standard merging mechanism of merg sort.
I'm wondering what the value k has to equal for the modified version of merge sort to equal the original version of merge sort in terms of rum time complexity.  This is a conceptual exercise by myself for myself.  Code and or an explanation is appreciated.

Comment: excuse my spelling errors...

Answer (score 0):

Your n/k-way merge is O(n^2/k) (explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026219/why-is-k-way-merge-onk2/11026570#11026570)). Each of your individual insertion sorts are O(k^2). Observe that for any value of k, your overall running complexity will remain O(n^2); therefore, no value of k will allow your modified merge sort to be O(nlogn)