# Generating all divisors of a number given its prime factorization

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, primes, factorization

I want to find all divisors of numbers in range [1,10<sup>7</sup>] . I know it can be solved in O(sqrt(n)). But had to run sieve of Eratosthenes before this which can be easily modified to get prime factorization of a number(by keeping track of one of the prime factors of every number). So i wondering would it be more efficient to generate all the factor using its prime factorization?
Let n = p<sub>1</sub><sup>k<sub>1</sub></sup> * p<sub>2</sub><sup>k<sub>2</sub></sup>*....*p<sub>m</sub><sup>k<sub>m</sub></sup>

I think this notation can be obtained in O(m+Σk<sub>i</sub>) after sieve.
I came up with following code to generate factors after a bit of thinking:

```
int factors[]={2,5};        // array containing all the factors
int exponents[]={2,2};      // array containing all the exponents of factors
                            // exponents[i] = exponent of factors[i]
vector <int> ans;           // vector to hold all possible factors

/*
*   stores all possible factors in vector 'ans'
*   using factors and exponents from index l to r(both inclusive)
*/
void gen(int factors[],int exponents[],vector<int>& ans,int l,int r)
{
    if(l==r)                        
    {
        int temp = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<=exponents[l];i++)
        {
            ans.push_back(temp);
            temp *= factors[l];
        }
        return;
    }
    gen(factors,exponents,ans,l+1,r);
    int temp=factors[l];
    int size = ans.size();
    for(int i=1;i<=exponents[l];i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            ans.push_back(ans[j]*temp);
        }
        temp *= factors[l];
    }
}
```

I think its Time complexity is at least Ω(no of factors) = Ω(∏(1+k<sub>i</sub>)).

So my question is:
1) Is it faster to generate factors this way than normally(O(sqrt(n)) loop method)?
2) Can the code given above be optimized?

Comment: See whether [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992904/enumerate-factors-of-a-number-directly-in-ascending-order-without-sorting) is relevant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first most obvious optimization is to preallocate the answers vector.  You know exactly how many factors there will be (since you already gave the formula as ∏(1+k<sub>i</sub>) ).

If you manage the stack yourself instead of using recursion, you'll get the most optimal solution (each factor will require only 1 lookup and 1 multiplication).

Something like this?

```
int factors_count = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
{
    factors_count *= 1+exponents[i];
}
ans.resize(factors_count);
ans[0] = 1;
int count = 1;
for (int stack_level = 0; stack_level < r; ++stack_level)
{
    const int count_so_far = count;
    const int prime = factors[stack_level];
    const int exponent = exponents[stack_level];
    int multiplier = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < exponent; ++j)
    {
        multiplier *= prime;
        for (int i = 0; i < count_so_far; ++i)
        {
            ans[count++] = ans[i] * multiplier;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't even tried compiling it, so caveat emptor.

Answer (score 0):

My methods for this:

```
public static <T> Set<List<T>> generatePowerSet(List<T> list) {
        Set<List<T>> powerSet = new HashSet<>();
        generatePowerSet(list, 0, new ArrayList<>(), powerSet);
        return powerSet;
    }

    private static <T> void generatePowerSet(List<T> list, int index, List<T> current, Set<List<T>> powerSet) {
        if (index == list.size()) {
            powerSet.add(new ArrayList<>(current));
            return;
        }
        // Exclude the current element
        generatePowerSet(list, index + 1, current, powerSet);
        // Include the current element
        current.add(list.get(index));
        generatePowerSet(list, index + 1, current, powerSet);
        current.remove(current.size() - 1);
        // Skip duplicate elements
        while (index + 1 < list.size() && list.get(index) == list.get(index + 1)) {
            index++;
        }
        generatePowerSet(list, index + 1, current, powerSet);
    }
    public SortedListSet<Long> getDivisors(ArrayList<Long> primeFactors){
        SortedListSet<Long> divisors = new SortedListSet<>();
        Set<List<Long>> powerSet = generatePowerSet(primeFactors);
        for (List<Long> innerList:powerSet){
            long divisor = 1;
            for (long innerListEntry:innerList){
                divisor *= innerListEntry;
            }
            divisors.add(divisor);
        }
        return divisors;
    }
```

Comment: Is this Java or C#? This question is tagged C and C++. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992904/enumerate-factors-of-a-number-directly-in-ascending-order-without-sorting).