# Why is tail call optimization not occurring here?

Tags: c#, recursion, factorization, tail-call-optimization

We are using recursion to find factors and are receiving a StackOverflow exception. We've read that [the C# compiler on x64 computers performs tail call optimizations](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1235):

> JIT definitely does tailcals when running optimized code and not debugging.

Running `dotnet --configuration release` gets this far in our program:

```
...                      
7214 is a factor of 1234567890
7606 is a factor of 1234567890
10821 is a factor of 1234567890
11409 is a factor of 1234567890                

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

Why is tail call optimization not occuring?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const long firstCandidate = 1;
        WriteAllFactors(1234567890, firstCandidate);
    }

    private static void WriteAllFactors(long number, long candidate)
    {
        if (number % candidate == 0)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"{candidate} is a factor of {number}");
        }

        candidate = candidate + 1;
        if(candidate > number / 2)
        {
            return;
        }

        WriteAllFactors(number, candidate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't tail call recursion require that you return the value?

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm guessing that's a rhetorical question. :)

Comment: There's no return at all; what stops this from running forever?

Comment: @EricLippert Sorry, a recent edit removed the return. Fixed.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin, no it's an "I don't remember the details of tail-call recursion" question.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992904/enumerate-factors-of-a-number-directly-in-ascending-order-without-sorting), though in different language(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSadov provides the explicit reason for this in his response:

> Generally JIT emits tail calls when it finds that profitable.

In addition, he goes on to state:

> This is a part that is not expressible in C#. Unlike inlining, which
>   can be forced via attributes, tailcalling cannot be currently forced.
>   If one needs to write the code like emitted by EmitMethodCall, he
>   cannot use C#.

So the answer is that while tailcalls are definitely available and used, there is no way to either predict when they will be used or force them to be used in C#.

Comment: I feel surprised that it is not profitable to prevent a StackOverflow exception. If that's the answer, though, then that's the answer.